# CSS to style the second header th element in table with a 0 starting index

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to apply some special styles to the second `th` header element in html below.

What CSS would I use for this?

I tried this CSS but it doesn't work:

```
table > tr > th:nth-child (2) {
  /*some styles*/
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sunil</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Toronto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Dallas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ricky</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>El Paso</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: by default a TH is already bold

Comment: ... and clearly this is a case where a reset style sheet, or other local CSS, has overridden that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed (the automatically-inserted) `tbody` from your selector:

```
table > tbody > tr > th:nth-child(2) {
    /* styles */
}
```

You could, of course, simply use a less-specific selector in this case:

```
th:nth-child(2) {
    /* styles */
}
```

This works because a `<th>` is always with a `<tr>` and always within a `<table>`; the only ancestor that can vary (within the table) is `tbody` (which could, instead, potentially be either `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` instead).

Comment: Or just `th:nth-child(2)` unless there's a case where you have a `th` that's *not* part of `tr`.